# If $\varphi(a) = \varphi(b)$ and $K=\ker \varphi$ why does $aK = bK$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $\varphi(a) = \varphi(b)$ and $K = \ker \varphi$

then $a^{-1}b \in K$ and $b^{-1}a \in K$

where $aK$ is left coset such that $aK = \{ ak | k \in K \}$

then $b \in aK$ and $a \in bK$

I follow that so far. Then, my textbook says

$aK=bK$

Why is this so? Can someone do a simple proof?

Comment: Use bidirectional inclusion when you have to show that two sets are equal

Comment: What is $\;K\;$ ,what is $\;\phi\;$ ....groups, homomorphism....or what?

Comment: $\varphi$ is a homomorphism. I said $K = \ker \varphi$. user133281 has the right proof for this. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
\begin{align*}
x \in aK &\iff a^{-1}x \in K \iff \varphi(a^{-1}x) = e \\&\iff \varphi(a)^{-1}\varphi(x) = e \iff \varphi(x) = \varphi(a) \\
&\iff \varphi(x) = \varphi(b) \iff \varphi(b)^{-1}\varphi(x) = e \\ &\iff \varphi(b^{-1}x) = e \iff b^{-1}x \in K \\
&\iff x \in bK,
\end{align*}
$$
so $aK=bK$.

Comment: perfect! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For any subgroup $H$ and $h\in H$, $H=\{hh': h'\in H\}$.  So, $K=\{a^{-1}bk: k\in K\}$.